# Images Upload Wordpress on front-end with Ajax

Tags: ajax, image, wordpress, upload, frontend

i definitely need your helps. I need to code a wordpress page with uploading an image ( like a logo of a customer ) through ajax because i have to change the page to paypal checkout page. So i need upload the image file to the server first, then checkout that order so i have to use ajax in my page. But i have not done with this from 2 days ago.

I has looking for many ways on the webs but some code is with postID ( but i dun need it, i just need upload the file on the server through ajax on wordpress front-end page, thats all ! ). And others show how to upload in back-end ( unhelpful too ).

Has anyone have any idea about this ?

Comment: `I has looking for many ways on the webs but some code is with postID ` -if you're a programmer, you can deal with that...

Comment: This is the first time i code with wordpress.

Comment: Thanks Reigel, you make me stronger and believe in myself :D so i coded it by myself so it works now like a charm. Thank you so much.